# Calling a function inside another function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I have defined a function named larger to find the larger number between two arguments (num1, num2). Now I want to use this function inside another function called "largest" which gets an array and return the largest number of that array, but I`ve got stuck. Can anybody help me with that?
Here is my codes:

```
function larger(num1, num2){
  var largerNumber = 0;
  if (num1 > num2){
   largerNumber = num1;
  } else {
      largerNumber = num2;
  }
return largerNumber;
}

function largest(array){
 for (var i = 0; i < array.length ; i++){
  for (var j = 0; j < array.length ; j++){
   if (array[i] != array[j]){
     //I don`t know if I am doing it right
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to sort an array? What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: your largest function will loop n squared times (where n is array.length) ... to get the largest value in an array only requires a loop n long - so, no you're not doing it right ... also, lookup `Math.max` for an even simpler solution

Comment: The easiest way to 'know if you're doing it right' is to try a simpler example, and see whether it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through the array once, keeping only the largest:

```js
function larger(num1, num2){
  var largerNumber = 0;
  if (num1 > num2){
   largerNumber = num1;
  } else {
      largerNumber = num2;
  }
return largerNumber;
}

function largest(array){
 let largestNumber = array[0];
 for (var i = 1; i < array.length ; i++){
  largestNumber = larger(largestNumber, array[i]);
 }
 return largestNumber;
}

var test = [1, 53, 352, 22, 351, 333, 123, 5, 25, 96];
console.log(largest(test));
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max):

```js
function largest(array) {
  return Math.max.apply(Math, array);
}
console.log(largest([5,-2,7,6]));
```

If you really want to use a custom binary `larger` function, consider [`[].reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
function larger(num1, num2) {
  return num1 > num2 ? num1 : num2;
}
function largest(array) {
  return array.reduce(larger, -Infinity);
}
console.log(largest([5,-2,7,6]));
```

Answer (score 3):

The simpliest solution is tu use a max tmp value. This way, you only need to do one iteration over all your array.

```
function largest(array){
    var max = array[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < array.length ; i++) { // So we start at 1
        max = larger(max, array[i]);
        // Or use this : if(array[i] > max) max = array[i];
    }
```

**AS SAID BY ORIOL**

I didn't check the length of the array, the above solution work only if the array.length > 0.

Otherwise, you'll have to check it usingsomething like this instead of `var max = array[0];`

```
function largest(array){
    var max = -Infinity; 
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length ; i++) { Start at 0
        max = larger(max, array[i]);
}
```

It really depends on the ergonomics of your IHM.

Comment: Note the code assumes `array.length > 0`. Usually I prefer initializing `max = -Infinity` and starting the loop at `i=0`.

Comment: Wep, didn't check this one. But I assume that OP will take care of this. (Ahah, i'll try to update my answers)

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to find the maximal value, you should go with Oriol's answer: `Math.max`

If you are looking for a way to call one function from another you can do it like this:

```
function first_function() {
  //code of first function

  //call to the other function
  second_function();
}

function second_function() {
  //code of second function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the first element of array to a variable, if next element in array is greater set variable to that element; continue process, return variable

```js
function largest(array) {
 if (!array.length) return;
 for (var i = 0, curr = void 0; i < array.length ; i++) {
   if (curr === void 0) curr = array[i];
   else if (curr < array[i]) curr = array[i];
 }
  return curr
}

console.log(largest([2,20,2000,2,7]));
```